# What is not in scope?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

[History Stack Exchange is for historians and history buffs.](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  [Denialism is not history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_negationism); denialism is not in scope for History Stack Exchange.  Questions or answers that rely on denialist sources or arguments are out of scope and will be deleted promptly.

If the content relies on and supports historical sources and methods, it is in scope.  If the content relies on racism or hatred or is fundamentally at odds with the [Code of Conduct](https://history.stackexchange.com/conduct), and it does not belong on History Stack Exchange. History Stack Exchange should be a safe place focused on history.

The community is encouraged to downvote and flag denialist sources/arguments/questions/answers.  Moderators will delete this content without waiting for community moderation.

Comment: In addition, we have a community-close-reason for push questions. Posts trafficking in denialism are almost invariably push questions designed to push their theory, and should be closed accordingly.

Comment: This is a case where the perfect is the enemy of the good. Attempting to define "denialism" will enmesh me in Popper's tolerance paradox. I'm going to rely on the good will of the community.